# Affine contractions from linear contractions?

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, linear-transformations, affine-geometry

Let $V$ be a linear space. Consider a contractive linear map $M:V\mapsto V$,
$$
\|Mv\|\leq \|v\| \quad \text{for all vectors } v\in  V.
$$
Now, for some fixed vector $c\in V$, the question is to sort out whether or not 
$$
\|Mv+c\|\leq \|v+c\| \quad \text{for all vectors } v\in  V
$$
is also true.

UPDATE: Sorry, it is stated, is trivially not true. Suppose $M v= v/2$, take $v=-c$, then $\|M (-c)+c\|=\|c\|/2>0=\|v+c\|$.

Consider instead the case that $M$ does not change the sum of components of $v$, $\sum_i (Mv)_i=\sum_i v_i$ for all $v\in V$?

Answer (score 0):

In general no. Take $Mv = \frac 12 v$. Fix $c \in V$ (nonzero, since otherwise the inequality holds trivially) and let $v = -c$.  Then $$\|Mv + c\| = \frac 12 \|c\|$$ but $$\|v+c\| = 0.$$

Comment: Note that in particular this works for $V = \mathbb R$, with $M$ being the $1 \times 1$ matrix whose sole entry is $\frac{1}{2}$, $c = 1$, and $v = -1$.  Often when statements like the one you asked about are false, they're false for very simple examples, and looking for those is a good skill to develop.

Comment: Many thanks, I realize it too late :)

Comment: What about if $M$ does not change the sum of components of $v$, $\sum_i (Mv)_i=\sum_i v_i$?